# AjaxControl toolkit exception

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a gridview with edit button on it. On clicking the edit button a modal popup is shown which is working correctly in vs2008. When I converted the application to vs2012, on clicking the edit button I am getting the following JavaScript exception.

```
0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback
argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in
configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security 
purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate
from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and  
expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to  
register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

I have tried the following changes

```
1.Added enable event validation=”false” in the page header –not worked
2.Added toolscript manager instead of script manager-not worked
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: have you tried setting enable event validation=”false” in web.config?

Comment: nope...where do we set event validation=”false” in web.config

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/950xf363(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks..tried it now instead of popup, textboxes are coming inside gridview with update/cancel button.